# Code signing to prevent piracy

Tags: android, signing

I have an app on the Android Market, and recently I was made aware that another publisher had uploaded it under a different name, and was giving it away for free.

I've never uploaded an apk that wasn't signed correctly in the official Google manner. What I'd like to know is, is code signing intended to prevent this kind of thing happening?

Can someone remove the license and add their own? Is this easy to do?

Answer (score 1):

They'd have to do more than just take your APK and upload it under their account.  The namespace which you create is unique to your application.  So, at a minimum they've reverse engineered some of your code.

Comment: I'm interesting specifically in the signing, what exactly is the purpose and is it used to stop piracy? Or is it just to verify an apk was signed by a specific developer?

Comment: Signing just makes sure the APK was created by you. It's not encrypted or anything and can still be unpacked/reverse engineered by anyone.

Answer (score 1):

As long as somebody is able to pull your apk off of their device and re-package it, nothing can really stop them from uploading it to the market on their own. Report it to [Google](http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/bin/request.py?contact_type=publisher) and you may want to look into using the [licensing service](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html).

Comment: This was a while ago, I did report it to Google and it was removed. I'm using the licensing service also, but this doesn't appear to have made much differnce. The publisher also had a bunch of other pirated apps also.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing preventing someone from doing this. All code signing does is ensure your application has not been modified from the version you published. i.e. a modified version cannot be installed on top of an unmodified version. If your app has simply been republished without modification, it is no different from your own version. Only the distribution source has changed.

You will need to implement some kind of licensing to prevent piracy. Android code signing is not like iOS code signing (where apps on the store as actually signed by Apple, not just you).